# stream with inherited class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, stream

I have two class:
The parent class: Vehicle

```
class Vehicle {
    private:
        string manufacturer;
        int cylinder;
        Person owner;
    public:
        Vehicle();
        Vehicle(const Vehicle& theObject);
        friend istream& operator >>(istream& inStream, Vehicle& object);
        friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outStream, const Vehicle& object);
};
```

and the child class: Truck
I overload `operator<<` and `operator>>` so that I can use `cout` and `cin` with my class Truck. Here is my definition with these two operators:

```
class Truck : public Vehicle {
    private:
        double loadCapacity;
        int towingCapacity;
    public:
        Truck();
        Truck(const Truck& object);
        friend istream& operator >>(istream& inStream, Truck& object);
        friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outStream, const Truck& object);
};

istream& operator >>(istream& inStream, Truck& object) {
    cout << endl << "Insert truck: "; inStream >> object;
    cout << "Insert load capacity: "; inStream >> object.loadCapacity;
    cout << "Insert towing capacity: "; inStream >> object.towingCapacity;
    return inStream;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& outStream, const Truck& object) {
    outStream << object;
    outStream << endl << "Load capacity: " << object.loadCapacity;
    outStream << endl << "Towing capacity: " << object.towingCapacity;
    return outStream;
}
```

When I try to use

```
Truck object;
cin >> object;
cout << object
```

It does not work out as I think. Can anybody explain why?
Thank you

Comment: So we can not look into your head and we cannot see in it, what you think would happen. Please add more information, what is the result, what did you expect?

Comment: Provide more detail than "It does not work out as I think". What are you expecting/seeing?

Comment: Yes, I mean when I use Codeblocks, I can run the program but it shows "Segmentation fault".

Comment: What I would like to know is whether my functions of these two operators are correct or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inStream >> object` and `outStream << object` are both recursive calls because the static type of `object` is `Truck`, not `Vehicle`. Use a virtual `print` and `get` method that `Truck` overrides. Call `object.print(outStream)` in the inserter and `object.get(inStream)` in the extractor in order to achieve polymorphic I/O through inheritance:

```c++
class Vehicle {
private:
    string manufacturer;
    int cylinder;
    Person owner;
public:
    Vehicle();
    Vehicle(const Vehicle& theObject);
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << manufacturer << cylinder << owner;
    }
    virtual void get(std::istream& is) {
        is >> manufacturer >> cylinder >> owner;
    }
};

class Truck : public Vehicle {
private:
    double loadCapacity;
    int towingCapacity;
public:
    Truck();
    Truck(const Truck& object);
    void print(std::ostream& os) const {
        Vehicle::print(os);
        os << loadCapacity << towingCapacity;
    }
    void get(std::istream& is) {
        Vehicle::get(is);
        is >> loadCapacity >> towingCapacity;
    }
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inStream, Vehicle& object) {
    object.get(inStream);
    return inStream;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outStream, const Vehicle& object) {
    object.print(outStream);
    return outStream;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but are there any way to still keep these two functions of class Vehicle? As I know, class Truck can use any function with a parameter of class Vehicle because it is derived from Vehicle.

Comment: @PeaNguyen I wouldn't recommend it but all you have to change in your original code is `inStream >> object` to `inStream >> static_cast<Vehicle&>(object)` and `outStream << object` to `outStream << static_cast<Vehicle const&>(object)`.